# What does &(0,1) mean in jolt transformation?

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

[Here (click Convert 'prefix soup', to nested data item)](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/) is example of translating prefix json into nested json.

**Interesting string is**

```
"rating-*": "SecondaryRatings.&(0,1)"
```

I understand that `*` is regular expression for keys, `&` somehow refer to value, but what does `(0,1)` mean in [jolt](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See section `'&' Wilcard` in [Shiftr](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java) java doc.

Answer (score -1):

`//&1` means to go up one level, grab that value and substitute it in.